# best way to get a node's position in godot 3d

Tags: coordinates, godot, gdscript

I am very new to godot and in a 3d scene what is the best way to get a node's coordinates. I have looked into it a bit and simply writing "translation" gets me a Vector3 with the positon of that node. I do not understand this and it seems strange. Again what is the best way?

Also i do not understand the difference between a global/local position. Anyone mind explaining it?

Answer (score 2):

Translation is how far it has moved away from origin. This is effectively the position of the node in 3D space.

Global is the absolute position or the actual position in the virtual world.

Local is relative to the parent’s position.

If we have Parent at global position (or with global translation) `Vector3(1, 0, 0)` and Child at local position `Vector3(0, 0, 0)` we can say that the *Child’s global position is at* `Vector3(1, 0, 0)`